# Karaf out of memory error

Tags: out-of-memory, apache-karaf, java-memory-model, karaf

I am using Karaf 2.3.0 for deploying my OSGi activator bundles and exposing my remote services as rest enabled. Thigs are working fine. Only once I got an out of memory error on the karaf logs (attaching the logs), after which I was not able to access my rest serviced. When I took the heap and thread dump after an hour of server crash (my karaf process is still running even after the OOMemory error), I could find nothing big in the dumps. Checked the process using jvisualvm (karaf process Xmx-1024 MB) and the memory and cpu consumptions are the bare minimal. But I am not bot able to access any of my services. Trying to access the services keeps trying for minutes without any error until timeout. I do not see the server log printing any signs of my access as well..  Is'nt the process supposed to stop once the out of mem error occurs? How can i identify what could caused the problem? Attaching the logs below

```
2014-07-16 12:19:51,461 | WARN  | qtp1863802945-52 | ServletHandler                   | lipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog   70 | 52 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.7.v20120910 | /services/alertThreshold/F5/VirtualServer
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.$Proxy11.service(Unknown Source)[69:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:447)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:70)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)[59:org.eclipse.jetty.security:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1038)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:117)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:374)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:972)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:74)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:920)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)[54:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[54:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)[53:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)[53:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[52:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[52:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_17]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted$2.invoke(HttpServiceStarted.java:210)[69:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.1.3]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)[51:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:1.1.2]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2014-07-16 12:19:51,460 | WARN  | 2.168.31.36:5000 | cluster                          | verMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable  117 | 115 - org.db.mongo - 1.0.0.201407140926 | Exception in monitor thread during notification of server state change
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)[:1.7.0_17]
    at com.mongodb.ServerDescription.getShortDescription(ServerDescription.java:467)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.ClusterDescription.getShortDescription(ClusterDescription.java:191)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.updateDescription(BaseCluster.java:158)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.MultiServerCluster.updateDescription(MultiServerCluster.java:240)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.MultiServerCluster.onChange(MultiServerCluster.java:149)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.MultiServerCluster.access$100(MultiServerCluster.java:40)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.MultiServerCluster$DefaultServerStateListener.stateChanged(MultiServerCluster.java:111)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.DefaultServer$DefaultServerStateListener.stateChanged(DefaultServer.java:104)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(ServerMonitor.java:114)[115:org.db.mongo:1.0.0.201407140926]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_17]
2014-07-16 12:19:51,458 | ERROR | qtp1863802945-55 | ContainerResponse                | .spi.container.ContainerResponse  406 | 92 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.15.0 | The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.newDecoder(UTF_8.java:68)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.<init>(StringCoding.java:131)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.<init>(StringCoding.java:122)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:187)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:416)[:1.7.0_17]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder$BSONInput.readUTF8String(BasicBSONDecoder.java:544)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:230)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:154)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBDecoder.decode(DefaultDBDecoder.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:141)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:164)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:292)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:271)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:237)
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.getMore(QueryResultIterator.java:137)
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.hasNext(QueryResultIterator.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:551)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
    at com.testing.apptest.search.dao.ObjectSearchDao.getObjects(ObjectSearchDao.java:1648)
    at com.testing.apptest.core.service.ObjectDictionaryManagement.getObjectList(ObjectDictionaryManagement.java:572)
    at com.testing.apptest.core.service.ObjectDictionaryManagement.getObjectDict(ObjectDictionaryManagement.java:358)
    at com.testing.apptest.core.service.alertSettings.ThresholdSettingsManagement.getObjectList(ThresholdSettingsManagement.java:239)
    at com.testing.apptest.rest.ThresholdSettingsRest.getDeviceList(ThresholdSettingsRest.java:315)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)[92:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.15.0]
2014-07-16 12:19:51,457 | ERROR | qtp1863802945-57 | ContainerResponse                | .spi.container.ContainerResponse  406 | 92 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.15.0 | The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2014-07-16 12:19:52,669 | WARN  | qtp1863802945-57 | ServletHandler                   | lipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog   70 | 52 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.7.v20120910 | /services/notificationCenter
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.$Proxy11.service(Unknown Source)[69:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:447)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:70)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)[59:org.eclipse.jetty.security:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1038)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:117)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:374)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:972)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:74)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:920)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)[54:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[54:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)[53:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)[53:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[52:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[52:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_17]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted$2.invoke(HttpServiceStarted.java:210)[69:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.1.3]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)[51:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:1.1.2]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2014-07-16 12:19:52,669 | WARN  | qtp1863802945-55 | ServletHandler                   | lipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog   70 | 52 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.7.v20120910 | /services/alertThreshold/F5/WideIp
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.$Proxy11.service(Unknown Source)[69:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:447)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:70)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)[59:org.eclipse.jetty.security:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1038)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:117)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:374)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:972)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:74)[70:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:1.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:920)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)[54:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[54:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[58:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)[53:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)[53:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[52:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[52:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_17]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted$2.invoke(HttpServiceStarted.java:210)[69:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:1.1.3]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)[93:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.15.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)[51:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:1.1.2]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.newDecoder(UTF_8.java:68)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.<init>(StringCoding.java:131)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.<init>(StringCoding.java:122)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:187)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:416)[:1.7.0_17]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder$BSONInput.readUTF8String(BasicBSONDecoder.java:544)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:230)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:154)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBDecoder.decode(DefaultDBDecoder.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:141)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:164)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:292)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:271)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:237)
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.getMore(QueryResultIterator.java:137)
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.hasNext(QueryResultIterator.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:551)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
    at com.testing.apptest.search.dao.ObjectSearchDao.getObjects(ObjectSearchDao.java:1648)
    at com.testing.apptest.core.service.ObjectDictionaryManagement.getObjectList(ObjectDictionaryManagement.java:572)
    at com.testing.apptest.core.service.ObjectDictionaryManagement.getObjectDict(ObjectDictionaryManagement.java:358)
    at com.testing.apptest.core.service.alertSettings.ThresholdSettingsManagement.getObjectList(ThresholdSettingsManagement.java:239)
    at com.testing.apptest.rest.ThresholdSettingsRest.getDeviceList(ThresholdSettingsRest.java:315)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)[92:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.15.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all a process isn't supposed to stop after a OOMError. An OutOfMemoryError is a Throwable and therefore can be handled by the virtual machine. In your case the bundle in question did get removed and therefore the memory consumption is ok again. You'll need to restart your application Bundle and maybe the Pax Web one too. 
Regarding your exception I've seen that there is an issue with an ArrayCopy, you seem to have a lot of "big" objects in your application, maybe just increasing the Heap-Size is already enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Xmx (JAVA_MAX_MEM and JAVA_MAX_PERM_MEM) in $KARAF_HOME/bin/setenv

Comment: In my case the variables in setenv are not being used, it always starts with -Xmx=512M
Any suggestions?